# Is there a way to access a value of the previous row in a trigger with sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

i have a table `ops` containing operations on an account, the balance of this account and an index giving the chronological order of these operations.

```
idx    op_sum    account_balance
1      200       200
2      -30       170
4      -20       160     -- this operation has idx=4 so the balance is accurate!
3       10       180
```

A trigger is ensuring that `idx` stays unique.

```
CREATE TRIGGER on_insert_before BEFORE INSERT ON ops
WHEN (SELECT op_sum FROM ops WHERE idx=NEW.idx)
BEGIN
    UPDATE ops SET idx=idx+1 WHERE idx>=NEW.idx;
END;
```

I now want to add a trigger that could calculate the `account_balance` when adding a new operation while considering the chronological order and updating the rows with a superior `idx` if any.

As an example if i do this: `INSERT INTO ops(idx, op_sum) VALUES(2,-90);`

my table should look like that:

```
idx    op_sum    account_balance
1      200       200
3      -30        80
5      -20        70
4       10        90
2      -90       110
```

I tried things like that:

```
CREATE TRIGGER on_insert_after AFTER INSERT ON ops
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE ops SET account_balance=
        (CASE WHEN idx=1
            THEN op_sum
            ELSE (SELECT account_balance FROM ops WHERE idx=idx-1)+op_sum
        END);
END;
```

But it didn't work (to be more exact this part doesn't work `(SELECT account_balance FROM ops WHERE idx=idx-1)`).

I have also been experimenting with recursive common table expressions, that would give me the accurate results:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
    cnt(x,y,z) AS (VALUES(1,200,200) UNION ALL
    SELECT
        x+1,
        (SELECT op_sum FROM ops WHERE idx=x+1),
        z+(SELECT op_sum FROM ops where idx=x+1)
    FROM cnt where x<(select max(idx) from ops))
SELECT x,y,z FROM cnt;
```

But i would like to know if there is a way to do it inside of my table, with triggers.

Comment: `idx` and `idx` refer to the same value. You already used `NEW` in the other trigger. Read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html).

Comment: @CL with `WHERE idx=NEW.idx-1` the trigger wouldn't iterate over the complete table and wouldn't update the rows with a superior `idx`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the new value from a different row, you must use a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery):

```
    UPDATE ops SET account_balance=
    (CASE WHEN idx=1
        THEN op_sum
        ELSE op_sum + (SELECT account_balance
                       FROM ops AS previous_ops
                       WHERE previous_ops.idx = ops.idx - 1)
    END);
```